# Error to remove text from text function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to remove the text. I'm using the following function.

```
 var ta=$('title', item).text();
```

The out put of this is "Cases That Charge On-The-Go(video)".
I want to remove the "(video)" from the text. plz let me know ho

Comment: Can you provide the HTML markup for this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ta = $('title', item).text().replace("(video)", "");
```

And if you want to remove any text between the parenthesis:

```
var ta = $('title', item).text().replace(/\(.*?\)/, "");
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/VNbjg/

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
ta = ta.replace("(video)", "");
```

So, to replace the text in the element try the following:

```
$("title", item).text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace("(video)", "");
});
```